# Flutter can't get dependancies to launch the project on the android emulator

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm installing my new mac, I reinstalled flutter and android studio.
But when I launch my project on the android emulator, during the build I've got the following issues.

It happens even with a new project

```
flutter create test
cd test
flutter run
```

I can't understand what should I do for the android studio can solve is dependencies

Can you help me please?

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.10.
     Required by:
         project :app > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.10.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.10/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.10/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
...
and this for a lot of dependencies
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem my gradle doesn't take into account my personal registry.
I set it only my maven setting, I should do the same for the gradle